# how to loop or iterate html code for the same components

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, iteration

The html code below is written to display a container with 4 text-area,3 images and 3 labels :

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
            <textarea class="form-control3" rows="3" placeholder="Clue 1"></textarea>
            <textarea class="form-control4" rows="3" placeholder="Answer"></textarea>
            <input type="text" class="form-control1" placeholder="10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control2" placeholder="Rejected">
            <div>
                <img src="images/up.png" width="13px" ;height="13px">&nbsp;
                <div class="blank"></div> 
                <span class="badge badge-danger">100</span>
                <img src="images/down.png" width="13px" ;height="13px">&nbsp;
                <div class="blank"></div>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">50</span>
                <img src="images/eye.png" width="20px" ;height="20px">
                <div class="blank"></div> <span class="badge badge-danger">120</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form-inline .form-control3 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.has-warning .form-control4:focus {
    border-color: #66512c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #c0a16b;
}
.has-error .form-control1:focus {
    border-color: #843534;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
}
.has-error .form-control2 {
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
}
```

I want multiple containers to display in a single html page. My question is, is there a method to write the html and css code only once and use it for other containers too without repeating the code again and again (Like some iteration or looping method or any other)?

Also, i would like to stylize and position my images in a css instead of using the style elements height and width in my html code itself. I tried using a separate div tag for images and aligning it.But its not working. Could you please help me with these two.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any Javascript libraries, such as jQuery, at present?

Comment: Can you explain what's `width="13px" ;height="13px`

Comment: GregL, No. I haven't used any Javascript libraries. Would it be better to use it ?

Comment: Mr. Alien, i used the width and height to position my images. But i do not want to use it in the html code. i want to use it via css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery to make copies of the div. If you are a person with only HTML and css I am sorry I dont think there is any way. If the HTML is from any webserver PHP or .NEt server side we can make multiple copies.

Comment: Okay. Thankyou. What is it exactly that i should look for in Jquery ? No. The html is not from any webserver

Comment: Mr. Mithun, Thank you so much. i used the jquery clone() function and it worked. Thanks a ton.